# I cant modify a gradient in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was trying to see how it was the gradients in a file I found but I cant see the sliders of one of the figures, why does this happends?[image]

Comment: Hi Amairani409, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Very very trivial, I just needed to click on the gradient window and toggle to fill mode, it had switched to stroke.

Also, googled why that happens and apparently if you have transparent gradient on your stroke, the gradient tool won't let you modify the gradient.

One of those things that Adobe takes on and stops developing I think.

If I've helped you, mark this question!

Comment: I cant really see were I should change it

Comment: See here http://xyztutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/illustrator-gradient-transparency_thumb.jpg

Comment: yes that was it! thank you very much!, seems that the shape also had a solid fill thank you for your help!